# how to center the content inside a div using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a website that is working fine on large devices ,on mobile device I am trying to center the icon below the slider  using this code below in the class icn

```
.icn{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

but it is not centered. 
The website I made is in www.devmakk.com/tution

Comment: this is a repeated question ,plz search b4 asking.

Comment: please tell me proper which icn you need to change

Comment: why this question that has been answered nearly Graham's number times is even upvoted?

Comment: @ctf0 I know but there is a problem with my code

Comment: @user3447573 if u've searched u would know that `margin:0 auto;` doesn't work without specifying a width.

Answer (score 2):

Centered content will also need a width applied to it if it is `display:block`.

```
.icn{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:20px;
    display:block; // this is needed.
}
```

Otherwise, the parent container will just need to have `text-align:center;` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align:center` If you provide your relevant code in a fiddle i woul have been able to test it

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the display of the icon to block
for example

```
.icn{
display:block
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Don't forget display:block otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
.icn{
margin-Left:auto;
margin-Right:auto;
}
```